# batch create folder by date with subfolders

Tags: date, batch-file

I try to write a script that mounts a netshared folder.
Then it should create a folder in this directory named by the date like `20181025`. In this folder there have to 2 folders like 01 and 02.
If all the folders are created files should be copied into the folders but only the files with a timestamp like the folders date.
Is it possible to zip the mainfolder after that?

My try:

```
@echo off 
SetLocal
m:
cd \folder\destination
mkdir %date:~6,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~0,4%
cd ??the folder I created??
```

Can I copy the files with forfiles?
I dont know how to help myself.. hopefully u do.

Comment: You usually use, commands such as `Copy`, `XCopy` or `RoboCopy` to copy files, but you could of course do that as part of the command string in `ForFiles`. To find out how to do it, read the command help, and try it within a test environment. To get the usage information, I've referred to as command help, open a Command Prompt, type the command followed by a space and `/?`, e.g. `Cmd /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Im a little bit further right now.

```
@echo off
SetLocal enableextensions
m:
cd \folder\destination
set day=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
mkdir %day%
cd %day%
PushD "\\networkpath\"
forfiles /d +%date% /c "CMD /c if @fdate==%date% copy @fname M:\folder\destination\001
PopD
forfiles /d +%date% /c "CMD /c if @fdate==%date% copy @fname M:\folder\destination\002
PopD
EndLocal
```

This is working for me. But it would be smarter if I could directly zip those folders. To send the zip folder via mail is without using Powershell not possible?

Comment: I tried to run this script as far as it goes on the server but while running I detected a permission conflict. On the the domain admin is logged on. But when I run the script with admanistrativ permissions the netshare can not be accessed. if I continue withous explicit permissions it fails in the copy section. Some ideas anyone?